# Routing by linux iptables

Tags: linux, routes, virtual-machine, iptables

I have 3 virtual machines called vm1 vm2 and vm3. I want to ping from vm1 to vm3 via vm2.
vm1 has an interface eth0 having IP adress 192.168.221.10. Similarly, vm3 has eth0 having IP adress 192.168.221.11. vm2 has 2 interfaces which are eth1 (192.168.221.1 ) and eth2 (192.168.221.2). I want to control connections on vm2 and route them with the commands below

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -i eth2 -j DNAT --to 192.168.221.1        
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -i eth1 -j DNAT --to 192.168.221.11
```

However I cannot reach vm3 from vm1 in this way. Any idea of what is the problem.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have enabled IP Forwarding on VM2 as your VM2 is acting as a router.

I've also posted an article on [How to configure Ubuntu as a router](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/07/how-to-configure-ubuntu-as-router.html) using IPTables.